# How to replace spectrum view in color panel with color picker?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

I am new to Illustrator. I am just finding this color panel really hard to use. How do you pick a gray color from that spectrum. 
Before Illustrator, I used Coreldraw a lot, where there is no spectrum but easy to use color well (or color picker!) in which you can easily choose colors. I just hate the spectrum view, is there any way to replace it with color picker?

[image]

Comment: No, but if you choose the hsb option form the hamburger menu then you have the same axes as the picker in the sliders.

Comment: Ok I think thats as close to what I want. Thanks for replying man

Answer (score 2):

Well. Corel Draw indeed has a lot of color representations models. They have RGB cube, CMY Cube, HSB, Tone...

And I agree that that particular one you are showing has no sense and it is useless, and as far as I know, there is no way to change it. Just play with the sliders or use the Internal color picker. :o(

Comment: Yeah moving on from one program to another is really like moving to a different city! Illustrator is the choice of professionals so everyone says. But it needs to improve its workflow..By now coreldraw has become a beast in terms of usability but I guess it will always be a distant competitor to Illustrator. As a consumer thats fine with me as long as Adobe studies how efficient Coreldraw's workflow is.

Comment: Agree. It would better for everyone to have more competition. Monopoly is not good. I keep mentioning Corel Draw and Afinity Design every time I can.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really an extra click. You anyhow need to *double-click* on the color to enter the color picker.

Or you can just press <kbd>F6</kbd> which will open the **Color Panel**

Now click anywhere on that "spectrum" to pick the color you want.

Comment: Yeah color picker needs double click. But what if it were in place of spectrum color box.. right now when you pick color from spectrum, you further need to fine tune it with sliders (well at least I do!). But with picker you can choose exact color in one or two clicks.. and also its H slider is much bigger to properly work with.